# How to fix extraneous input ' ' expecting, in antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Hello when running antlr4 with the following input i get the following ***error***
image showing problem

[[image: image showing problem[1]]

I have been trying to fix it by doing some changes here and there but it seems it only works if I **write** every **component** of **whileLoop** in a **new line**.

Could you please tell me what i am **missing here** and why the problem **persits**?

```
grammar AM;

COMMENTS :

'{'~[\n|\r]*'}' -> skip

;

body : ('BODY' ' '*) anything | 'BODY' 'BEGIN' anything* 'END' ;


anything : whileLoop | write ;

write : 'WRITE' '(' '"' sentance '"' ')' ;

read : 'READ' '(' '"' sentance '"' ')' ;

whileLoop : 'WHILE' expression 'DO' ;

block : 'BODY' anything 'END';

expression : 'TRUE'|'FALSE' ;

test : ID? {System.out.println("Done");};


logicalOperators : '<' | '>' | '<>' | '<=' | '>=' | '=' ;

numberExpressionS : (NUMBER numberExpression)* ;

numberExpression : ('-' | '/' | '*' | '+' | '%') NUMBER ;

sentance : (ID)* {System.out.println("Sentance");}; 

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9]* ;



**`strong text`**
```

Comment: did you use ANTLR  Works to pass the same input and get the visual AST?

Comment: I Believe I am using antlr4. Though because of my lack of knowledge in this field I am not sure if I somehow using antlworks

Comment: try to install the ANTLR Works and that will give you the visual AST and where is failing your input in your grammar and where a specific token match with a certain rule. That is for debugging purposes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lexer rules produce conflicts:

`body : ('BODY' ' '*) anything | 'BODY' 'BEGIN' anything* 'END' ;`

vs

`WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;`

The critical section is the `' '*`. This defines an implicit lexer token. It matches spaces and it is defined above of `WS`. So any sequence of spaces is not handled as `WS` but as implicit token.

If I am right putting tabs between the components of whileloop will work, also putting more than one space between them should work. You should simply remove `' '*`, since whitespace is to be skipped anyway.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. I could have sworn that the only reason I put it there was because it had an error but it seems that is not the case.

Comment: @CoronA Does that mean we shouldn't use explicit whitespace (' ') anywhere if we are using the whitespace WS, in lexer declaration?

Comment: Yes. One has to decide if whitespace should be skipped or not.